Why did the writing of magic bowls stop?
We have the archaeological remains of thousands of "magic bowls" written by Jews from the 3rd - 7th century (source). After that period the existence of these bowls seems to dwindle and soon disappear. I would like to know if there are any particular reasons that the writing of these bowls declined from the 7th century and on.
Example of a bowl


If I'm not mistaken, bowls were still written in certain communities much later on. But I expect that different types of segulot come and go in fashion.

Could you explain what writing a bowl is?

Could the Muslims have banned magic bowls when they conquered Persia?

@Dude https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incantation_bowl#In_Judaism

17th century Rabbi (and Av Beit Din of Amsterdam) Moshe Zacuto includes instructions on how to make them in his book "Shoreshei Shemot", so it's quite possible the practice never died out

That could be decent evidence that the practice persisted longer than the questioner realized, but unless this is a usual practice somewhere today, it just pushes forward the end date several centuries and the question remains why did it end.

Is this question on topic here? It seems to be about Jewish history (as opposed to history of Judaism),  which is described as "generally off-topic". Also, although it is arguably asking about Jewish practice, (a) it is not in the sense of "what to do or why", and (b) the practice is 'Jewish' in the sense of "Jews did it" (as it seems based on archaeological finds mentioned in a Wikipedia article on the more general topic of "incantation bowls"), not that "Judaism prescribed it".

@TamirEvan I don't understand how this can be off topic. this practice is prescribed by Judaism (it is a form of amulet). Would the cessation of idolatry be off topic since it is not prescribed by was something Jews did?
